# SQL Combine multiple rows into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

How do I combine these? I want it into 1 row and the SUM of the item is 10. Combine not the sum of all rows that shows.

```
ItemID  Name    Discription   ENHET1    ENHET2  ENHET3  SUM 
1       Adel        CD        NULL      NULL    NULL    10
1       Adel        CD        NULL      X       NULL    10
1       Adel        CD        X         NULL    NULL    10
```

Alternatively:

```
ItemID  Name    Discription   ENHET1    ENHET2  ENHET3   
1       Adel        CD        NULL      NULL    NULL
1       Adel        CD        NULL      X       NULL    
1       Adel        CD        X         NULL    NULL
```

And I can make a join with the sum separately?

Desired result:

```
ItemID  Name    Discription   ENHET1    ENHET2  ENHET3  SUM 
1       Adel        CD        X         X       NULL    10
```

Comment: I am amazed !! how could these tables used in real world ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange table. However, you can simply aggregate and use MIN or MAX on the columns:

```
select 
  itemid, 
  min(name), min(discription), min(enhet1), min(enhet2), min(enhet3), min("sum")
from mytable
group by itemid;
```

Comment: Thanks ALOT! and for extremly fast answer =D

Comment: Is it possible to make it dynamic? so if we add a new enhet it just apears?

Comment: As a general rule: a data model is static; if you add data, you add rows, so the queries stay the same. Once you add columns to your model and you want your queries to take them into account, you will have to change your queries. Your database design looks bad (holding redundant data), which may be the reason for your intention to have a query automatically reacting to more columns ...

Comment: So the best solution would be to change your database design, e.g. one table `Item(ItemID, Name, Discription, Amount)` with `ItemID` being the primary key, and one table `Item_Enhet(ItemID, EnhetNo, Value)` with `ItemID` + `EnhetNo` as primary key. But of course it is always possible to have such query dynamic: Use an app that you write in a programming language (C#, Java, ...). Execute a query to get the column names for the table, then use the result to build the final query und execute this.

Comment: I cant change the DB design its how the application speciallist have set up AX. But thanks for the  input